# Unknown error in xpath (using xmlpullparser)

Tags: android, xml, xpath, xmlpullparser

I am using `XmlPullParser` to open a file and `XPath` to get the root. (Later I will modify my code to get the `idx` node)

However, I am getting the following error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath.
```

I've searched on the internet but haven't found anything that could resolve this issue.

```
try{
    XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.x1);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String askFor2 = "/root";
    NodeList creaturesNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(askFor2, xpp, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    Log.d("", "");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"run thread failed":ex.getMessage();
    Log.e("bm run catch", err);
}
```

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <child index="1">
        <idx index="1" />
        <idx index="2" />
        <idx index="3" />
        <idx index="4" />
        <idx index="5" />
        <idx index="6" />
        <idx index="7" />
    </child>
</root>
```

Your time and help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong attribute to evaluate method. Try using InputSource,

```
try{
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xm));
    String askFor2 = "/root";
    NodeList creaturesNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(askFor2, is, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    Log.d("", "");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("bm run catch", err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you should be passing an InputSource as the second argument to xpath.evaluate(), not a parser. Keep in mind that XPath in general may need to walk an entire document tree, so except in some special restricted cases, it cannot work with a streaming parse: you need to read in the whole document, construct an in-memory tree model and apply XPath to that.